# Does the 500 rule apply to astrophotography with a telescope?

Tags: photography

On clear nights, I mount my Samsung Galaxy S10 to my 130mm aperture telescope and take pictures of certain deep-sky objects. Recently, I took pictures of the Orion Nebula. In order to get the optimal single-exposure pictures, I set the ISO to 320 and the shutter speed to 4 seconds. The shape of the nebula's cloud and the colors were relatively apparent, but unfortunately, I noticed streaks just beginning to appear in my pictures. The 500 rule says that the exposure time is not enough to create streaks, but I'm looking through a telescope instead of just a DSLR with a lens attached to it.

Does the [500 rule](https://www.slrlounge.com/glossary/500-rule-photography/) apply to photography *through a telescope*?

Comment: It's much more of a guideline than a rule, it's also been called, the 200, 400, 500, and 600 "rule".  It depends a lot on the resolution of your camera, so you have to experiment with your equipment.  But it does apply as much to telescopes as any other lens.

Comment: https://www.scantips.com/lights/stars.html

Comment: 500 Rule also is known as 200, 400, 500, 600,etc as given by @GregMiller. So a better term would be the NFX rule